# awk/sed convert positive value to negative in a semicolon separated file

Tags: replace, sed, awk, gsub

I have a file which is built up like this:

```
1233;mc3; limit;1
946;mc3; limit;14545
0843;mc3; limit;2
443;mc3;Short  ;1012
1309;mc3;Short  ;1
1247;mc3;Short  ;1121
989;mc3;Short  ;1
1340;mc3;Short  ;14545
170;mc3;Short  limit;1
105964;mc3; rep;2000000
4934;mc3; rep;1
3028;mc3; rep;14545
```

The only thing I know for sure is that everyhting is ';' separated.

I want to edit the value in the fourth column to a negativ value. In the file, this value will always be positive.

What I've come up with so far is this:

```
[usr@serv] cat list | awk -F";" '{gsub ("^","-",$4);print}'
123213 mc  limit -1
946 mc  limit -14545
08743 mc  limit -2
4493 mc Short   -1012
13009 mc Short   -1
12147 mc Short   -1121
9989 mc Short   -1
13490 mc Short   -14545
1780 mc Short  limit -1
1054964 mc  rep -2000000
49324 mc  rep -1
30828 mc  rep -14545
```

But as you can see it removes the ";". What am I doing wrong here?

It doesnt really matter to me if I use awk or sed, or if I edit the original file or print it to a new file. I just want to convert the value after the third ";".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rev filename | sed 's/;/-;/' | rev
```

Comment: Oh, *that's* clever. +1.

Comment: You should not use `cat` for commands that can read file itself. `rev filename | sed 's/;/-;/' | rev`  And with 654 points, you should know how to use code tags.

Comment: you're right, jotne, modified my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `OFS` set to `;`.  You can also do like this:

```
awk -F\; '{$4=0-$4}8' OFS=\; file
1233;mc3; limit;-1
946;mc3; limit;-14545
0843;mc3; limit;-2
443;mc3;Short  ;-1012
1309;mc3;Short  ;-1
1247;mc3;Short  ;-1121
989;mc3;Short  ;-1
1340;mc3;Short  ;-14545
170;mc3;Short  limit;-1
105964;mc3; rep;-2000000
4934;mc3; rep;-1
3028;mc3; rep;-14545
```

Comment: No need to `$4=0-$4`, `$4=-$4` suffices.

Comment: +1 , the accepted answer works, and looks cool, however this line is (much) better than that one. this awk line processes the file only once. The other one 3times in 3 processes. If the input is as small as the question, it is ok. however, when you hit a big file....

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*$\)/-\1/' filename
```